# SQL (Presto): How to pull locations within X mile radius of lat/lon pont

Tags: sql, geospatial, latitude-longitude, presto, radius

I have a bunch of stores with their own Latitudes and Longitudes. I'm trying to pull data that is within a 2 mile radius of each point. Eg. How many stores are within 2 miles of each store. What is the best way to go about this?

I know rounding the lat/longs to the tenth (18.4, -66.2) can essentially give me 5 mile radius, but how do I get more granular. I'm not sure how granular rounding to the 100th (18.4, -66.21) gets me in terms of miles, but seems too small of a radius.

Date is stored as:

- Store Name (string)
- Latitude (double)
- Longitude (double)

---

Comment: I don't know presto, so this may not be helpful, but here's how I would start in postgres... Create a table with each store-to-store combination. If you have 22 stores, you have 231 combinations. Then this query would return the distance for each combination...     select loc1, loc2, FN_CALC_DISTANCE(loc1_lat, loc1_lon, loc2_lat, loc2_lon) from temp_location_combos

Answer (score 3):

What you want is spatial join:
https://prestodb.io/blog/2020/05/07/local-spatial-joins

Just join a table with itself, on condition that distance between two points is below 2 miles, and aggregate. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.store_name, 
  (COUNT(*) - 1) AS neighbors    -- subtract 1 for self
FROM stores a JOIN stores b
ON ST_Distance(ST_Point(a.longitude, a.latitude), 
               ST_Point(b.longitude, b.latitude)) < 2 * 1609
GROUP BY a.store_name
```

Make sure you have a relatively fresh Presto installation, I think Presto got it optimized around end of 2018, and it would run as plain cross join before that - which would be too slow.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks mate! For my context, what is the 2 * 1609 doing?

Comment: 2 * 1609 is two miles (from question) in meters